# jquery get position from targeted element

Tags: jquery

how can i get position of an element from targeted element

```
<div class="photo_container">
     <p>abasdfasdfsadf</p>
       <div id="drag_item" class="box">
      <img src="abc.jpg" id="image_placed" >  
    </div>
</div>

$(function() {
   var p = $("#image_placed").position('.photo_container');
   alert(p.left);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is to get the position of the parent `.photo_container`:

```
var p = $("#image_placed").closest(".photo_container").position();
```

Comment: i want position of the image_placed from the .photo_container this alerts 10 in every case check this http://jsfiddle.net/tbwr3/